# Create Models from DBT Macros

Tags: dbt

I want to create multiple `dbt` models (materialized as `views`)
I have a `macro` that creates the sql statement based on various parameters.

My current strategy is to create a list of SQL statements in `macros/query_tables.sql` and then try to call the `macro` from within  `models/mat_tables.sql` .

The `dbt build` runs but the `target` SQL is empty.

```
create or replace view mat_tables
  
   as (    

  );
```

Any suggestions for running such a process?

#### `macros/query_tables.sql`

```
{% macro query_tables() %} 
{% set query_list = [] %}
    {% set tables = ['MEDIA_LOADED ', 'MEDIA_DOWNLOADED', 'MEDIA_PLAYED'] %}
    
    {% for table_name in tables %} 
        {% set query %}   
            with events_{{table_name)}} as (
                select
                    user_id,
                    session_id,
                    {{ dbt_date.from_unixtimestamp("created_at", format="seconds") }}  as session_dt,
                    count(*) as cnt_{{table_name}}
                from
                    {{ table_name }}
                where
                    {{ dbt_date.from_unixtimestamp("created_at", format="seconds") }}  > '{{ var("start_date") }}'
                group by
                    1,2,3
            )
            select
                *
            from
                events_{{table_name}} 
        {% endset %}

        {% set query_list = query_list.append(query) %}
        {{ log(query, info=True) }}

    {% endfor %} 
    {{ return(query_list) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

The  `models/mat_tables.sql`  code that runs the process is

```
{{ config(materialized='view') }}

{% set event_tables_query= query_event_tables() %}

{% for table_query_tmp in event_tables_query %}
        {% do run_query(table_query_tmp) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dbt model really needs to map 1:1 with a materialized asset in your RDBMS. In other words, you need one model file per view you'd like to create.

`run_query` will execute a query in your database, which in this case is just a select statement. The data from that select statement can be returned to the jinja context with `{% set data = run_query(table_query_tmp) %}`, but your `do` statement will not persist that data anywhere (and in this case, that is the wrong approach -- `run_query` is really for returning small amounts of data to the jinja context for the purposes of dynamically generating sql).

In other words, you can simplify your macro quite a bit:

```sql
-- macros/get_media_query.sql

{% macro get_media_query(table_name) %}
with
    events_{{ table_name) }} as (
        select
            user_id,
            session_id,
            {{ dbt_date.from_unixtimestamp("created_at", format="seconds") }}
            as session_dt,
            count(*) as cnt_{{ table_name }}
        from {{ table_name }}
        where
            {{ dbt_date.from_unixtimestamp("created_at", format="seconds") }}
            > '{{ var("start_date") }}'
        group by 1, 2, 3
    )
select *
from events_{{ table_name }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And then you create 3 model files that call the macro with the right table name:

```sql
-- models/media_loaded.sql
{{ config(materialized='view') }}
{{ get_media_query('MEDIA_LOADED') }}


-- models/media_downloaded.sql
{{ config(materialized='view') }}
{{ get_media_query('MEDIA_DOWNLOADED') }}


-- models/media_played.sql
{{ config(materialized='view') }}
{{ get_media_query('MEDIA_PLAYED') }}
```